# Automate domain expiration date query with Bash

Tags: linux, bash, automation, domain, whois

I need to implement a Nagios Plugin with Bash and check domain expiration date in real time with Whois (most of the domains are `.com.ar` but not all of them).

In my script has the next code:

```
#!/bin/bash
DOMAIN=google.com.ar
WHOIS_DATE=`wget -O - 'https://www.whois.com/whois/'$DOMAIN | grep 'expire' | awk '{print $2}'`
CURRENT_DATE=$(date +%s)
EXPIRE_DATE=$(date --date=$WHOIS_DATE+%s)
DIFFERENCE=$(($EXPIRE_DATE - $CURRENT_DATE))
CONVERSION=$((60*60*24))
DAYS=$(($DIFFERENCE/$CONVERSION))
```

With `$DAYS` variable I can monitor the expiration date of the domain. My issue resides in that the first time the script run, the whois data not found and forces me to open a web browser, paste the URL: `https://www.whois.com/whois/google.com.ar` to enable it the first time and then the next executions of the sctipt runs well.

I tried with Wget and Curl but without success.

Answer (score 1):

Running your Wget command outside of your script shows this output:

```
wget -O - 'https://www.whois.com/whois/google.com.ar' | grep 'expire' | awk '{print $2}'
--2019-10-31 15:23:38--  https://www.whois.com/whois/google.com.ar
Resolving www.whois.com (www.whois.com)... 64.91.226.82
Connecting to www.whois.com (www.whois.com)|64.91.226.82|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                       [ <=>                ]  46.82K  --.-KB/s    in 0.03s   

2019-10-31 15:23:39 (1.55 MB/s) - written to stdout [47939]
```

While that progress status stuff is not harmful, I find it confusing for debugging a task like this. Instead, run the same command but with the `-q` (aka: quiet) parameter set an he output is cleaner; notice the date is the output:

```
wget -q -O - 'https://www.whois.com/whois/google.com.ar' | grep 'expire' | awk '{print $2}'
2020-07-08
```

That said, the output is cleaner but it seems like there is some DNS resolution stuff on your side. So instead, why not use the `whois` that is running from the shell like this:

```
whois 'google.com.ar' | grep 'expire' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Cleaner and faster and no need to involve an HTTP call with Wget.

Comment: @JakeGould other thing, the output of whois in my server is:
`This TLD has no whois server, but you can access the whois database at
http://www.nic.ar/`